# RAISERROR―How to distinguish with SqlException?

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2005, sqlexception, raiserror

I have some 3-4 stored procedures ― which I can modify if needed ― that  use `RAISERROR` to inform my application of some fatal errors on the database side. Some of these stored procedures are executed from the C# side with `ExecuteNonQuery`, while other are executed with `ExecuteReader`. At the moment, I am wrapping these command in a `try { ... } catch (SqlException ThisSqlException) { ... }` block, but the problem is that this exception will be thrown in at least two scenarios I must deal with separately:

1) Errors with the connection itself, or with faulted or type-mismatched parameters; and

2) Errors that occur whenever I use `RAISERROR` explicitly.

Since this is a WCF application, I must return to the client application different feedback based on the nature of the exception (whether it was due to a `RAISERROR` command or not). How can I, then, distinguish between both situations?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`RAISERROR` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) includes a msg_id parameter, which can be used to identify the type of error. This value is supplied to the application through the [`SqlException.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) property. In this way, you can identify any exception raised by a stored procedure that includes a custom error message that is defined in the system.

If `RAISERROR` is called with a text string error message, then `Number` will be 50000.

Comment: you can specify a custom number for msg_id to recognize your own specific errors, but the number needs to be registered in the database sys.messages table first and needs to be > 50000. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 5):

When you catch a `SqlException`, you can inspect its `Errors` collections which contains the detailed error messages.

Those [`SqlError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) objects contained very detailed information - including error code, message and so forth.

Using that information, you should be able to easily distinguish between connection-based errors, or errors that your raise yourself.