# How to catch errors raised by raiseerror function?

Tags: c#, sql

We have a legacy application which sends messages to the application using `raiseerror` like,

```
  raiserror('A generic error',16,1)
```

Now I need to know how to catch these messages in C#,

```
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
    // 
  }
```

Currently `SqlException` has everything including custom messages. I wanna filter that.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509209/raiserror-how-to-distinguish-with-sqlexception)?

Comment: @Guy yes thanks found out the error 50000 may be work for us